# what does means Binding with no source property in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight, binding

I am little new and I have a doubt in relation with databinding.

To bind something I usually use `{binding propertyName,...}` but in some post/blogs I can see the kind of code like `ItemsSource="{Binding}"`.  Why not use `ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}"`?

What are the differences?

Thank you! :=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some times the current `DataContext`  **is** the collection that supplies the items for some ItemsControl like a `ListBox`.  In which case there is no property to bind to, the source object as a whole is the value to be assigned to the `ItemsSource` property.  That's what `ItemsSource="{Binding}"` means.  When no property path is specified the binding's `Source` object is passed in.

Whereas `ItemsSource="{Binding YourCollection}"` means find the property called `YourCollection` on the `Source` object and pass its value to `ItemsSource`.